# Diplay a Text field when clicking a CommandLink in VF page

Tags: visualforce, commandlink, visibility

I would like to display a Text Field when clicking Command Link ( Title:Add Filter Logic ). After the clicking of command link, the link title should be renamed to Clear Filter Logic. It would be great, if anyone let me know, how to do this.[image]

Comment: What did you tried for this. becasue it is a very easy thing

Comment: Hi Tushar,  I am not sure, how to give the condition in Render part of the  InputText component.    <apex:inputText id ="logic"  disable ="false" rendered="{()}" >  . It would be greatt, if you provide some sample code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is pure Apex & Visualforce trick.

Have 2 properties in your apex controller.

```
public String buttonText{get;set;}
public Boolean showInput{get;set;}
```

In your VF page, your commandLink-

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!doStuff}" reRender="theInputSection">{!buttonText}</apex:commandLink>
```

Your input field section

```
   <apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="theInputSection">
    <apex:inputText name="Input" value="{!SomeVariableName}" rendered="{!showInput}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
```

Now in your Apex controller, define the doStuff method & constructor

```
public MyController()
{
showInput = false;
buttonText = 'Add Filter Logic';
}

public PageReference doStuff(){
showInput = true;
buttonText = 'Clear Filter Logic';
return null;
}
```

Comment: Glad, I could help!